Extending C# syntax highlighting in vim
I am trying to create my own color scheme in the latest version of gvim and I have encountered a problem.
When I try to add a new group for syntax highlighting, for example I want the library connections to be highlighted in a certain color, i.e. the text after using.
I created a file ~/.vim/after/syntax/cs.vim and used the regular expression syntax match CSLibrary /\<using\ \zs[A-Za-z0-9_\.]\+/ in it
In my color scheme file, I gave this group a color hi CSLibrary ctermfg=36 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE
When using the command :syn list CSLibrary it is output that the highlighting group exists and even has the correct formatting.
When I execute the command match CSLibrary /\<using\ \zs[A-Za-z0-9_\.]\+/ in the current session without using syntax, the highlighting turns on.
How can I correctly create a highlighting group so that it highlights the text I need, please explain
